# OneSignal notification is not received on android but deliver from OneSignal console

Tags: react-native, push-notification, onesignal

i put my FCM credential on OneSignal console correctly and OneSignal verify it and saved it .And when i run my react-native code  via android device it shows that one user is active . and i send push notification from OneSignal console and its status become deliver but nothing comes on android device . But when i open my google firebase console then it show 0 users and 0 messages

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive push notifications, the Device needs to subscribe. if not check,

- whether your device has Google Play services installed and updated on it.
- whether device id gets or not.

for more about [OneSignal Android SDK Guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup)